# Power Set of a Power Empty Set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find ℙ(ℙ(ℙ(∅))).

I know that ℙ(∅) = {∅}.
Then, ℙ(ℙ(∅)) = {∅, {∅}, {∅,{∅}}**?**
so, ℙ(ℙ(ℙ(∅))) = {∅,{∅, {∅}, {∅,{∅}}}**?**
Is it? Will it be ok if someone explain to me this concept?

Comment: The number of elements of $PPP(\varnothing)$ is 4, so your set should have 4 elements (but curly brackets confuses me.)

Comment: How did you get 4?

Comment: The number of elements in the power set of $n$-element set is $2^n$.

Comment: Where did you get n?

Comment: $n$ is the number of elements you're taking the power set of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's easier if you consider $P(\varnothing)$ to be a one-element set, say $\{1\}$. Then it's pretty clear that $P(P(\varnothing))$ has to be precisely $\{ \varnothing, \{1\}\}$. So $P(P(P(\varnothing))) = \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\{1\}\}, \{\varnothing, \{1\}\}\}$.

Comment: How do you know the value of the next element?

Comment: What do you mean by "next"?

Comment: For  ℙ(ℙ(∅)) = {∅, {∅}}, how did you know the value will be {∅}, and for  ℙ(ℙ(ℙ(∅))) ={∅,{∅},{{1}},{∅,{1}}}?

Comment: If you have a one-element set, the only possible subsets are those that contain the element or not, which is how you get $P(P(\varnothing))$. For the next step, you now have just a two-element set, so you can have:

1. Neither element; 2. Element A; 3. Element B; 4. Both elements. That's what you see in the answer.

Comment: A few notes:
We have $P(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$. The [set-theoretic definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers#Definition_as_von_Neumann_ordinals) would be $0=\emptyset$ and $1=\{0\}=\{\emptyset\}$ (not $\{1\}$).
Finally, the substitution of $\{\emptyset\}$ has been made only two out of three times, so, writing $1$ instead of $\{1\}$, the answer would be $\{\emptyset,1,\{1\},\{\emptyset,1\}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

P(ø) = {ø}

P(P(ø)) = P({ø}) = {{ø}, ø}

P(P(P(ø))) = P(P({ø})) = P({{ø}, ø}) = {{{ø}, ø}, {{ø}}, {ø}, ø}

Comment: What does this add to the accepted answer?

Comment: I think the answer is fine, as opposed to the accepted answer this one stresses how one can compute the power sets using nothing but (string) substitution. In my experience, this is exactly in the spirit of set theory.